# Why float moves my button up

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with floating buttons inside my div. As soon as I set the float property on button, it not only moves left/right, but slightly changes position and moves up which is not what I want...

Here is what I'm working on

http://jsfiddle.net/o1u1cLbm/2/

```
<div id='wrapper' style='display:flex; height:88px;align-items:center;text-align: center;background-color:yellow'>
<div style="background-color:blue">
    <h1>
    Some header text
    </h1>
</div>
<div style='flex:1;background-color:red'>
  <div style='display:block; vertical-align:middle'>
     <button style="height:24px;">
         Some stuff
       </button>
     <button style="height:40px">
       Other stuff
     </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

The buttons must be in a container that will grow to max space after the title text. Now I want the first smaller button to be close to the title, and the big one on the right side like this

http://jsfiddle.net/o1u1cLbm/3/

```
<div id='wrapper' style='display:flex; height:88px;align-items:center;text-align: center;background-color:yellow'>
    <div style="background-color:blue">
        <h1>
        Some header text
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div style='flex:1;background-color:red'>
      <div style='display:block; vertical-align:middle'>
         <button style="height:24px;float:left">
             Some stuff
           </button>
         <button style="height:40px;float:right">
           Other stuff
         </button>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see after I add float property to the button it is not centered in the parent div anymore but attached to top.

How can I float the buttons without changing their vertical position with just css?

Comment: Why do you use inline styles?

Comment: To show quickly my problem, in my app styles are defined in css files

Comment: Great........:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `floats`, you can use `flexbox` and then use [`margin-left:auto`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) to last `flex-item`

```html
<div id='wrapper' style='display:flex; height:88px;align-items:center;text-align: center;background-color:yellow'>
    <div style="background-color:blue">
        <h1>
        Some header text
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div style='flex:1;background-color:red'>
      <div style='display:flex;align-items:center;'>
         <button style="height:24px;">
             Some stuff
           </button>
         <button style="height:40px;margin-left:auto;">
           Other stuff
         </button>
      </div>
      
    </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use `justify-content: space-between;` `to flex-container`

```html
<div id='wrapper' style='display:flex; height:88px;align-items:center;text-align: center;background-color:yellow'>
  <div style="background-color:blue">
    <h1>
      Some header text
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div style='flex:1;background-color:red'>
    <div style='display: flex;width: 100%;justify-content: space-between;align-items: center;'>
      <button style="height:24px;">
             Some stuff
           </button>
      <button style="height:40px;margin-left:auto;">
           Other stuff
         </button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `inline-block` just make your `div` a flex container:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
```

`justify-content: space-between` get you the effect of floating - see demo below:

```html
<div id='wrapper' style='display:flex; height:88px;align-items:center;text-align: center;background-color:yellow'>
  <div style="background-color:blue">
    <h1>
      Some header text
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div style='flex:1;background-color:red'>
    <div style='display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;'>
      <button style="height:24px;">
             Some stuff
           </button>
      <button style="height:40px">
           Other stuff
         </button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. float is not needed in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `display: flax;` don't need use floating in the flax there are native solutions [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hamik25/fct3fh0k/) you can find solution in JS Fiddle

Comment: It's `display: flex;`

Comment: In my example you will get what you want without floating 
http://jsfiddle.net/df3oLr5b/

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div id='wrapper' style='display:flex; height:88px;align-items:center;text-align: center;background-color:yellow'>
    <div style="background-color:blue">
        <h1>
        Some header text
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div style='flex:1;background-color:red'>
      <div style='display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between;'>
         <button style="height:24px;">
             Some stuff
           </button>
         <button style="height:40px;">
           Other stuff
         </button>
      </div>
      
    </div>
</div>
```